# IF - Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal

Tags: powershell, if-statement, hash, literals

Hello I am getting error "Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal." on the IF statement, where am I wrong

```
$Nests | ForEach-Object {
      $RecordMetrics = [pscustomobject]@{
            key = $_.key
            count = $_.doc_count
            if (key -like 'CBT99*') 
            {
              bo = 'CBT'
              SiteID = 1972
            }
           elseif
           {
            boperator = $map[$_.key.TrimEnd("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","-") ].boperator
            SiteID = $map[$_.key.TrimEnd("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","-") ].SiteID
           }
        }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a conditional statement in the middle of a hashtable literal like that.

You'll have to create the hashtable/dictionary first, then populate the relevant keys based on your conditional logic:

```
$Nests | ForEach-Object {
    # create dictionary with initial properties
    $properties = [ordered]@{
        key = $_.key
        count = $_.doc_count
        Host = ''
        OperatorName = ''
    }

    # conditionally add remaining properties
    if ($_.key -like 'CBT99*') {
        $properties['bo'] = 'CBT'
        $properties['SiteID'] = 1972
    }
    else {
        $properties['boperator'] = $map[$_.key.TrimEnd("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-") ].boperator
        $properties['SiteID'] = $map[$_.key.TrimEnd("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-") ].SiteID
    }

    # convert to custom object
    $RecordMetrics = [pscustomobject]$properties
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have the hashtable already created, but the condition in IF does not use the hashtable?

Comment: @GeorgiGochev If you read my answer closely, you'll see that I assign the new dictionary to `$properties`, and inside the if/else bodies I again write to `$properties`

Comment: Yes, this way I get some warnings, which were not present before                                             WARNING: Host skipped as it's value was null or empty, which is not permitted by InfluxDB.        
WARNING: OperatorName skipped as it's value was null or empty, which is not permitted by InfluxDB.
WARNING: SiteID skipped as it's value was null or empty, which is not permitted by InfluxDB.                                                                                                              Probably it creates object with empty properties?

Comment: It sounds like the code you're working on is not the same code as you posted.

Comment: These are tags to influx query, they come from object properties. The bigger issue is that only one member of the object gets inserted

Comment: @GeorgiGochev Then create the properties in the hashtable literal with empty _values_ regardless of whether you populate them in the if statement (I've updated the answer) - this way the columns will at least exist

Comment: It gives me errors  You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.   at  $properties['boperator'] = $map[$_.key.TrimEnd("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-") ].boperator
        $properties['SiteID'] = $map[$_.key.TrimEnd("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-") ].SiteID

Comment: Sounds like `$_.key` is `$null`. What does `$Nests` contain?

Comment: It contains key and doc_count properties, first is string, and second is integer